# Example for using bbox in treeview in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am not able us bbox in python.

code written

```
bx=ttk.Treeview.bbox(db_rslt,"aman don",column='4')
bx.configure(text='don')
```

It is giving me error like

```
File "C:\Users\Amandip\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 1191, in bbox
    return self._getints(self.tk.call(self._w, "bbox", item, column)) or ''
_tkinter.TclError: bad option "bbox": must be cget or configure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal Treeview `.bbox` example.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=2)
tree.pack()

#Add an item to the tree
iid = tree.insert('', 0, text='hello')

# Make sure GUI is rendered and item is visible before trying to get its bounding box
root.update()

bbox = tree.bbox(iid, column=0)
print('bbox', bbox)
root.mainloop()
```

**output**

```
bbox (201, 18, 200, 20)
```